# Why is the text transparent in Kivy. How to remove it?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm a novice in Kivy and get some problem with the text. When I make a button or something that can include the text, **I get a transparent text** and don't understand **why and how can I fix that**?
Ok. When I make a button I can add 'markup=1', but it doesn't work with TextInput or same.

Versions: Python 3.7, Kivy 1.10.1, Win7

```py
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.button import Button 


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text = "Hello!", 
        font_size = 100,
        background_color = [.5, 1, 1, 1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Results:

Without markup:

[image]

Same code, but using markup:

[image]

---

```py
#Another example:
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TextInput(font_size = 25)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Result:

Another example rezult:

[image]

Log:

[image]

Comment: Try install `angle`, `python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle`

Comment: I tried. " Requirement already satisfied: kivy.deps.angle in ... (0.1.7) "

Comment: Looks like maybe some kind of text provider bug, but I don't know what it could be exactly.

Comment: Did you changed the `kivy/data/style.kv` contents?

Comment: No, I didn't change any contents.

Comment: Could you try to reinstall kivy using https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html

Comment: Solved. I downgrade kivy.deps.sdl2 to 0.1.18 and the problem was fixed.